# Is an array of arrays supported in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was under the impression that an array of arrays is not allowed in javascript.  Is that still true?  Is the following object valid?

```
object: { array: [ [0],
                   ['1', '2']
                 ]
 }
```

Can someone please point me to examples of usage?  I've been using arrays of strings as a workaround.

Comment: Arrays of arrays were and are allowed. You code is valid with outer braces if you wanted an outer object.

Comment: `Is that still true?` it was never true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is allowed. Try this.

```js
var arrayObj = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];
console.log(arrayObj[0][0]); // first column/first row
console.log(arrayObj);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tiny example that's easy to follow.